# How to determine whether V3 is between V1 and V2 when we go from V1 to V2 counterclockwise?

Tags: matlab, vector, geometry, angle

I have three vectors V1, V2, and V3. Their origin points are on the axes' origin. How could I determine whether V3 is between V1 and V2 when I move around counterclockwise from V1 to V2?

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/1448ea8896.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/1448ea8896.jpg)

It can't be done with obtaining their angles and evaluating these kind of conditions (pseudo-code):

```
if angle(V3) > angle(V1) && angle(V3) < angle(V2) 
   printf("V3 is between V1 and V2") 
else 
   printf("out of the interval")
```

To see its defect, suppose that the `angle` function gives angles in the range of [-pi pi].  So, if angle(V1) = 120 (in degree), angle(V2) = -130 and angle(V3) = 150 then the answer (according to the above code) is "out of the interval" although if you move around counterclockwise from V1 to V2, it is between them.

You may suggest adding 2*pi to angle(V2) or something like that, but I've tried such things and it doesn't work.

I'm programming in MATLAB.

EDIT 1 : it is in 2D.

Comment: Why'd you remove the matlab tag? It helps give your question more views.

Comment: because the question is not MATLAB specific

Comment: The OP said they were doing the programming in MATLAB, so I assumed they would want MATLAB-coded answers.

Comment: +1 for fantastic hand drawn art!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are doing this in MATLAB, here is one solution that should work:

```
crossProds = [V1(1)*V2(2)-V1(2)*V2(1) ...
              V1(1)*V3(2)-V1(2)*V3(1) ...
              V3(1)*V2(2)-V3(2)*V2(1)];
if (all(crossProds >= 0) || ...
    (crossProds(1) < 0) && ~all(crossProds(2:3) < 0)),
  disp("V3 is between V1 and V2");
else
  disp("out of the interval");
end
```

**EXPLANATION:**

The cross product between the 2-D vectors **V1** and **V2** is stored in the first element of **crossProds**. This value will be greater than or equal to zero if the counter-clockwise angle between **V1** and **V2** is between 0 and 180 degrees, inclusive. In this case, when **V3** is between **V1** and **V2** in the counter-clockwise direction then the cross products **(V1,V3)** and **(V3,V2)** are also greater than or equal to zero. This explains the first logical check:

```
all(crossProds >= 0)
```

If the counter-clockwise angle between **V1** and **V2** is greater than 180 degrees, then the cross product of these two vectors will be less than zero. In this case, when **V3** is between **V1** and **V2** in the *clockwise* direction then the cross products **(V1,V3)** and **(V3,V2)** are also less than zero. Therefore, if these cross products are *not* both less than zero then **V3** must be between **V1** and **V2** in the *counter-clockwise* direction. This explains the next two logical checks:

```
(crossProds(1) < 0) && ~all(crossProds(2:3) < 0)
```

The above logical checks should cover all possible situations. The operators || and && are [short circuit operators](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html) in MATLAB: they will skip the second statements if they are not necessary. For example, if the first statement in an OR is true, there is no reason to check the second statement since only one argument in an OR needs to be true for the result to be true.

Comment: thanks, but it seems your methos is winding method. as I said to Nils Pipenbrinck, this method did not work.

Comment: I believe my method is quite different than Nils'. It involves cross products, but has different logical checks.

Comment: I didn't tag it as homework, Dinah did. I tagged it as matlab.

Comment: It seems to be working! but could you please explain more about it?

Comment: Sure, I'll update my answer with a detailed explanation soon.

Comment: your method works extermely effective...I tested it in hundreds of  complicated situations...I uesd it to determine whether a diagonal of a concave polygone is in or out of it. thanks very much...

Comment: @Himadri: When the code given above displays "V3 is between V1 and V2", then V3 is between V1 and V2 when we go from V1 to V2 in a *counter-clockwise* direction. When the code displays "out of the interval", then V3 is between V1 and V2 when we go from V1 to V2 in a *clockwise* direction.

Answer (score 3):

Calculate angle(V1), angle(V2) and angle(v3) (a1, a2, a3).

Modify a2 and a3 (add 2*pi if needed) so that

```
a1 <= a2 < a1 + 2*pi
a1 <= a3 < a1 + 2*pi
```

Now you simply have to compare a2 and a3.
V3 is between V1 and V2 is resulting a3 is inferior to a2.

Comment: your answer is right, but I could not select two answers as my final answer,even I hardly can say which is the better: yours or gnovice's answer....

Comment: I will evaluate to see which answer is faster tomorrow...thanks

Answer (score 2):

V1 is a red herring.  You're just going to confuse yourself thinking about 3 angles at once.

2. Rotate everything clockwise by angle(V1)
3. Normalize the remaining two angles to [0,360)

Now the question is simply to compare norm(angle(V2)-angle(V1)) and norm(angle(V3)-angle(V1)).

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat easier method for most other programing languages.

If V1, V2 and V3 are given vectors, and we need to decide weather V3 is between V1 and V2, and Ri = atan2(Vi) (which returns an angle in radians from -pi to pi):

**Clockwise**:

```
R1 -= R3;
R2 -= R3;

if (R1 < 0) R1 += 2 * PI;
if (R2 <= 0) R2 += 2 * PI;

return (r1 < r2);
```

For **counterclockwise**, just swap R1 and R2.

Answer (score -2):

To test this condition you have to calculate the winding of two triangles:

1. The triangle formed by V1, the origin and V3. This triangle must be counter-clockwise.
2. The triangle formed by V3, the origin and V2. This triangle must be counter-clockwise as well.

To test the winding of a triangle it's enough to check the sign of the 2D cross-product of the vertices.

The test looks like this (sorry - C-code):

```
int IsBetween (vector v1, vector v2, vector v3)
{
  float winding1 = (v1.x * v3.y - v1.y * v3.x);
  float winding2 = (v3.x * v2.y - v3.y * v2.x);

  // this test could be exactly the wrong way around. This depends
  // on how you define your coordinate system (e.g. is Y going up or down?)

  if ((winding1 <0) && (winding2 < 0))
  {
    printf ("V3 is between them\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf ("it's not\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this method works. for examplse, consider these vectors: angle(V1) = 10, angle(V2)= -10, V3 = 180. V3 is between V1 and V2 when we move around counterclockwise but your method says it isn't.

Comment: Kamran, could you draw a picture or give cartesian coordinates for your points?

Comment: thanks but as you may see in the picture, V1*V3 is positive and V3*V2 also is positive and V3 is between V1 and V2. but according to your method, it isn't between them!